# Pandas Import : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.api.extensions'

Tags: import, geopandas

I wanted to import geopandas as gpd, but the error message appears

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.api.extensions'.

What I have to do, to import geopandas?

## I installed geopandas via anaconda promt:

`C:\Users\sar>conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
>
> Solving environment: done
>
> All requested packages already installed.

## When i import geopandas, following code is shown in the console:

`import geopandas as gpd`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-a62d01c1d62e>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd

  File "C:\Users\sar\Anaconda\envs\codingingis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\sar\Anaconda\envs\codingingis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 15, in <module>
    from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _delegate_property

  File "C:\Users\sar\Anaconda\envs\codingingis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .array import GeometryArray, GeometryDtype

  File "C:\Users\sar\Anaconda\envs\codingingis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.api.extensions import ExtensionArray, ExtensionDtype

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.api.extensions'
```

## in array.py this code is not found:

`from pandas.api.extensions import ExtensionArray, ExtensionDtype`

Comment: Which version of pandas do you have? `import pandas` and `pandas.__version__`

Comment: I have pandas version: '0.22.0'

Comment: You need at least 0.23, which introduced extensions. Once you update pandas to latest version it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works for me. Now I have pandas version 0.25.2 and I can import geopandas.

Comment: Geopandas now added requirement to conda-forge recipe so this should not happen again.